# How to form variable string with HTML and corresponding quotations

Tags: javascript, json, syntax

I'm building a string of text using HTML and variables from a JSON file. The issue is that the quotation marks from the HTML are conflicting with the quotations from the js expression - specifically when I'm trying to build a URL from a string of a URL partial + a json variable.

Here's my code. Any help?

```
output += '<li><span><a>' +
          jobs[i].title +
          '</a></span><span>' +
          jobs[i].city +
          '</span><span><a href='http://user.theresumator.com/apply/'' +
          jobs[i].board_code +
          '><button>More Info ›</button></a></span></li>';
}
```

My desired outcome is something like:

```
<li><span><a>Social Impact Strategist (Los Angeles or New York)</a></span><span></span><span><a href="http://user.theresumator.com/apply/iefjlt"><button>More Info ›</button></a></span></li>
```

Comment: Escape them with `\'` or use `"` instead of `'` around.

Comment: Use `document.createElement` instead, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Escape your quotes with `\`:

```
output += '<li><span><a>' +
      jobs[i].title +
      '</a></span><span>' +
      jobs[i].city +
      '</span><span><a href=\'http://user.theresumator.com/apply/' +
      jobs[i].board_code +
      '\'><button>More Info ›</button></a></span></li>';
}
```

or use double quotes `"`:

```
output += '<li><span><a>' +
      jobs[i].title +
      '</a></span><span>' +
      jobs[i].city +
      '</span><span><a href="http://user.theresumator.com/apply/' +
      jobs[i].board_code +
      '"><button>More Info ›</button></a></span></li>';
}
```

The 2nd one will match your desired outcome with double quotes perfectly.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I understand the "escape" method but I'll look into it. The code you show outputs this string which isn't correct unfortunately: <a href="http://user.theresumator.com/apply/" iefjlt=""><button>More Info ›</button></a>

Comment: If the output is incorrect you should fix your code. The quotes problem has been addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code! I broke it out on a separate line and add double quotes by themselves contained in single quote.

```
output += '<li><span><a>' +
  jobs[i].title +
  '</a></span><span>' +
  jobs[i].city +
  '</span><span><a href=' +
  '"http://user.theresumator.com/apply/' +
  jobs[i].board_code + 
  '"' +
  '><button>More Info ›</button></a></span></li>';
}
```